# Flutter - Update items in a ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to change the order of widgets in a ListView as follows:

Widgets List

```
List<Widget> widgets = [const Text("Widget 1"), const Text("Widget 2")];
```

ListView

```
  ListView(children: widgets),

  Text("$widgets")
```

Function

```
() {
    widgets.shuffle();
    setState(() {
      widgets = widgets;
    });
  }
```

This way the order of widgets is changed in the TEXT but not in the list as I intended.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First solution:** Add `Key` to List `ListView` like this:

```
ListView(
   key: UniqueKey(),// <--- add this
   children: widgets,
),
```

also in your `Function` you don't need to pass widgets again:

```
() {
    widgets.shuffle();
    setState(() {});
  }
```

**Second solution:** you can use `SingleChildScrollView` and `Column` like this:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 50,
    width: 100,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: widgets,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: The previous answer solved the problem, this one did not.

Comment: @dnxinercode are you sure? I tested it and get the result. I added first answer too